# jQuery caoursel slider not updating width on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I've recently added a slider to my page and after some tweaking it works fine apart from one issue - when I resize the window, specifically make it smaller, the slider is not centered anymore and at low resolution on firefox the arrows go outside the window, here's the code for the slider

```js
$(function () {

console.log('DOM1');
$(document).ready(function () {


        var speed = 6000;
        var run = setInterval(rotate, speed);
        var slides = $('.slide');
        var container = $('#slides ul');
        var width = $('#slides ul');
        var elm = container.find(':first-child').prop("tagName");
        var item_width = container.width();
        var prev = 'prev'; //id of previous button
        var next = 'next'; //id of next button


        slides.width(item_width); //set the slides to the correct pixel width
        container.parent().width(item_width);
        container.width(slides.length * item_width); //set the slides container to the correct total width
        container.find(elm + ':first').before(container.find(elm + ':last'));
        resetSlides();



        $('#buttons a').click(function (e) {


            if (container.is(':animated')) {
                return false;
            }
            if (e.target.id === prev) {
                container.stop().animate({
                    'left': 0
                }, 1000, function () {
                    container.find(elm + ':first').before(container.find(elm + ':last'));
                    resetSlides();
                });
            }

            if (e.target.id === next) {
                container.stop().animate({
                    'left': item_width * -2
                }, 1000, function () {
                    container.find(elm + ':last').after(container.find(elm + ':first'));
                    resetSlides();
                });
            }


            return false;

        });

        $('#carousel').mouseenter(function () {
            clearInterval(run);
        }).mouseleave(function () {
            run = setInterval(rotate, speed);
        });


        function resetSlides() {
            container.css({
                'left': -1 * item_width
            });
        }

    });

    function rotate() {
        $('#next').click();
    }
});
```

```css
#carousel {
 position: relative;
 width:100%;
 margin-top: 10px;
 flex-basis: 100%;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
}
   .btn-bar{
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 @media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
width: 100%;
 }
    z-index: 4;
  }
  #buttons a {
 position: absolute;
 text-align:center;
 display:block;
 font-size:50px;
 float:left;
 outline:0;
 margin:-50px 60px;
 color:#FFFFFF;
 text-decoration:none;
 padding:9px;
 width:35px;
  }
a#prev{
 cursor: pointer;
 left: 0;
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid white;
 border-left: 1px solid white;
 transform: rotate(45deg);
 @media only screen and (max-width: 720px) {
   display: none;
  }
}
a#next{
 cursor: pointer;
 right: 0;
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 border-top: 1px solid white;
 border-right: 1px solid white;
 transform: rotate(45deg);
    @media only screen and (max-width: 720px) {
   display: none;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>OHIR &mdash; Imprint Media</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/3d5bb643659eb0b2a80acbe35c5073e5.png">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
        <div class="logo" id="OVERLAY"></div>
        <div class="ohir"><p class="col">OHIR</p></div>
        <nav class="col">
            <a href="#STORY">Książka</a>
            <a href="#FRAGMENT">Fragment</a>
            <a href="#AUTHOR">Autor</a>
            <button>KUPUJĘ</button>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <section class="OVERLAY hidden">
        <a>MODERNIST CUISINE</a>
        <a>IMPRINT MEDIA</a>
        <a>WYDAWNICTWO BARBELO</a>
        <button onclick="hideOverlayFunction()">POWRÓT</button>
    </section>
</header>

<main>
    <button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Go to top"><img src="images/arrow_up.svg"></button>
    <section class="container OHIR">
        <p>OHIR</p>
    </section>

    <section class="container ONBOARD">
        <div class="book"></div>
        <!--<img class='col' src="images/62d204dec2048b53e33842d869865586.png">-->
        <div class="border">
            <p> > Witaj na pokładzie Ohira.</p>
            <p> > Kiedy będziesz gotowy na podróż w nieznane?</p>
            <button>KUPUJĘ</button>

        </div>
        <div id="carousel">
            <div class="btn-bar">
                <div id="buttons"><a id="prev" onclick="prevFunction()"></a><a id="next" onclick="nextFunction()"></a> </div>
            </div>
            <div id="slides">
                <ul>
                    <li class="slide">
                        <div class="quoteContainer">
                            <p class="quote-phrase">Tak bardzo chciałbym odrodzić się jako Ohir.</span>

                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="authorContainer">
                            <p class="quote-author HAL">HAL 9000</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="slide">
                        <div class="quoteContainer">
                            <p class="quote-phrase">
                                Po przeczytaniu Ohira zbudowałem mój pierwszy ścigacz.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="authorContainer">
                            <p class="quote-author">Anakin Skywalker</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="counter">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="slide">
                        <div class="quoteContainer">
                            <p class="quote-phrase"></span>Chciałbym, żeby mój następny statek był taki, jak Ohir.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="authorContainer">
                            <p class="quote-author">Kapitan Jean-Luc Picard</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="counter">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="slide">
                        <div class="quoteContainer">
                            <p class="quote-phrase">Gdybym znów miał walczyć z cylinami, chciałbym mieć Ohira we flocie.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="authorContainer">
                            <p class="quote-author">Admirał William Adama</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
            <div class="counter">
                <span class="dot active"></span>
                <span class="dot"></span>
                <span class="dot"></span>
                <span class="dot"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <a class="anchor" id="STORY"></a>
    <section class="container STORY">
        <video id="videoStory" onpause="pauseFunction()">
            <source src="video/Ohir_fb%20video%20cover.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <button onclick="playFunction()" id="playBtn" title="play video">OHIR, OPOWIEDZ MI O&nbsp;KSIĄŻCE</button>
    </section>

    <section class="container FRAGMENT">
        <a class="anchor" id="FRAGMENT"></a>
        <div class="book"></div>
        <div class="col">
            <h3>ZAINTERESOWANY?</h3>
            <p>Przeczytaj darmowy fragment i&nbsp;dowiedz się jak zaczyna się przygoda z&nbsp;Ohirem. Wpisz swój adres e-mail, aby otrzymać PDF</p>
            <!--<input type="email" placeholder="e-mail">-->
            <form action="http://YOURWEBSITE/index.php?option=com_acymailing&ctrl=sub" method="post">
                <input id="user_email"   type="text" name="user[email]" value="" placeholder="e-mail" />
            </form>
            <button>PROSZĘ O FRAGMENT</button>
        </div>
        <div class="AUTHOR">
            <a class="anchor" id="AUTHOR"></a>
            <h3>SZCZEPAN AUGUST URAWSKI</h3>
            <span><p>Autor Ohira. Urodzony drogą naturalną w&nbsp;Warszawie, niemodyfikowany, bez dotacji unijnych. Rocznik 1983. Losy poprowadziły go ku ziemiom obcym, gdzie pracuje, tęskni, marzy i&nbsp;pisze. Pisał od kiedy pamięta. Bywały to scenariusze. Ku jego zaskoczeniu powstała też ogromna i&nbsp;fascynująca powieść SF.</p></span>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="mobile author">
        <div class="mobileAUTHOR">
            <h3>SZCZEPAN AUGUST URAWSKI</h3>
            <span><p>Autor Ohira.<br> Urodzony drogą naturalną w&nbsp;Warszawie, niemodyfikowany, bez dotacji unijnych. Rocznik 1983. Losy poprowadziły go ku ziemiom obcym, gdzie pracuje, tęskni, marzy i&nbsp;pisze. Pisał od kiedy pamięta. Bywały to scenariusze. Ku jego zaskoczeniu powstała też ogromna i&nbsp;fascynująca powieść SF.</p></span>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="container SHOP">
        <div class="book"></div>
        <div class="border">
            <h3>KUP KSIĄŻKĘ</h3>
            <span> > Piękne wydanie Ohira</span>
            <span> > 432 strony tekstu</span>
            <span> > Sprawna i&nbsp;tania wysyłka kurierska za 9.90</span>
            <h2 class="price">30 PLN</h2>
            <button>KUPUJĘ</button>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="container FOUR">
        <div class="book"></div>
        <div class="border">
            <h3>ZESTAW CZTERECH KSIĄŻEK</h3>
            <span> > Cztery książki drukowane</span>
            <span> > 432 stron każda</span>
            <span> > Sprawna i&nbsp;tania wysyłka kurierska za 9.90</span>
            <div class="priceROW"><h2 class="price">99 PLN </h2><button>KUPUJĘ</button></div>

        </div>
    </section>

</main>

<footer>
    <img class="col" src="./images/Imprint%20Media_logo.svg">
    <span>
        <p><b>Imprint Media Agencja Wydawnicza</b></p>
        <p>ul. Chmielna 2/31</p>
        <p>00-020 Warszawa</p>
    </span>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <span>
        <p>Znajdź nas na Facebooku!</p>
        <p>tel. 22 24 15018</p>
        <p>sklep@imprintmedia.pl</p>
    </span>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <span>
        <p>Jak wydać książkę?</p>
        <p>Poznaj ofertę Imprint Media</p>
        <p>Projektowanie i&nbsp;dystrybucja książek</p>
    </span>
</footer>
</body>
```

I really need help with this, if anyone could help me, that would be great.

Thank you!

Comment: Please also put your html; We can't help you without it.

Comment: Added the html, thanks btw, it's my first time posting here and I'm still a bit green when it comes to coding

Comment: @Dumdumdurum could you make a CodePen of your current working slider? I believe I have a solution for you but can't test with your current code.

Comment: Nevermind, I accidentally fixed it by making the site have a max width and centering it if the screen is wider than that